# "Available" is to "availability" as "required" is to what noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

If I want to know if an item is *available*, I can check for its *availability*.

What do I check for if I want to know if an item is *required*?

Comment: It's not technically a word, but I think most people would know exactly what you meant if you used "requirability".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check for its ***necessity***: whether it is necessary or not. While it's not strictly synonymous, if something is *required* it's normally *necessary*.

You could reverse the check and verify its *optionality*.

Answer (score 1):

"***Requirement***". Is there a requirement for something.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no noun for that adjective. Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries provide none. One can come across "requireness" on the web, but this seems to be a word formed by web users, especially programmers.